# VBA regexp pattern combining match and not matching a pattern

Tags: regex, excel, match, vba

Trying to extract valid phone numbers from a string with no visible delimiters between different data types.  In effect, the data around the potential phone number is random and irrelevant.

**What should be matched**. I am trying to match either one of the following:

- `[random garbage][optional '1'][optional '(']###[optional')'[[random or no white space]###-####[random garbage]` or
- `[random garbage]###[optional '-']###,[optional '-']####[random garbage]`

Only the 1st phone number is to be used, so I used `Global = False` in the code below. I could make it even more robust, but I've examined the data and this should be enough.

**Working pattern**.Here's a code snippet from a function (it returns the matching phone number) that contains the pattern that worked.

```vb
With regex
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = "1?(\(?\d{3}\)?\(s+)?|\d{3}-?)\d{3}-?\d{4}"
'this works but does detect an extension as explained above
End With
```

**What should not be matched**. I realized that I also need to search for an extension next to the phone number (i.e. `[phone number][white space]x#`) and **if that exists, to treat the phone number as invalid** (`.test` should evaluate to false).

**Failed attemps**. They all failed (even valid phone numbers had `.test` evaluate to false):

```vb
.Pattern = "1?(\(?\d{3}\)?\(s+)?|\d{3}-?)\d{3}-?\d{4}^(\s?x\d)"
'detect not([optional single white space]x#), added "^(\s?x\d)"
'or
.Pattern = "1?(\(?\d{3}\)?\(s+)?|\d{3}-?)\d{3}-?\d{4}^((\s+?)[x]\d)"
'detect not([optional multiple white space]x#), added "^((\s+?)[x]\d)"
```

Not sure how to combine positive match tests and negative (not) match tests in the same pattern.

**Work-arounds I've tried**. When I couldn't get it to work, I tried the following `Like` patterns (using VBA 'Like', prior to calling the function that utilized Regexp) and that also failed (all evaluated to false even with test strings that contained examples such as `"...1x2"` or `"5 x33"` or `"...7  x444"`; with patterns like `"*#x#*"`, `"*#{ x}#*"`, `""*#{  x}#*"`.

Here is the code snippet to test the Like function:

```vb
If Not (OrigNum Like "*#x#" Or OrigNum Like "*#[ x}#" Or OrigNum Like "*#[  x]#*") Then
    Debug.Print "No #x# in string"
    OrigNum = ExtractPhoneNumber(OrigNum)
Else
    Debug.Print "#x# in string"
End If
```

Every string evaluated ended up causing `"No x# in string"` to be displayed (evaluated to false), even when the string contained the above examples, which should have evaluated to true and `"#x# in string"` being displayed.

Dazed and confused for so long it's...OK, enough of the Led Zepp reference :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone number:

> - `[optional '1'][optional '(']###[optional')'[[random or no white space]###-####`
> - `###[optional '-']###[optional '-']####`

<sup>*I removed a comma I assumed as a typo, and also assuming the leading `1` is optional for both cases from what I read from your patterns.</sup>

Don't match:

> - `[phone number][white space]x#`

---

What you're looking for is [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

`(?! subexpression )` asserts for that subexpression from the current position and, if the subexpression matches, the match attempt fails (i.e. *not followed by*).
E.g. `(?!\s*x\d)` fails when the current position is followed by optional whitespace, an "x" and a digit.

Regex:

```regex
1?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-?)\s*\d{3}-?\d{4}(?!\s*x\d)
```

Code:

```vb
Public Function getPhoneNumber(strInput As String) As Variant
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    Dim matches As Object

    regex.Pattern = "1?(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|\d{3}-?)\d{3}-?\d{4}(?!\s*x\d)"
    regex.Global = False

    Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
    If matches.Count = 0 Then
        getPhoneNumber = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        getPhoneNumber = matches(0).Value
    End If
End Function
```

Results (*As it was, then again it will be; though the course may change sometimes*):

[image: Screenshot from Excel showing the input un column A and the result of the function in column B]

Comment: Thanks.  That worked and I did have that typo in the description.  One thing I still don't understand is the ":" in the match pattern.  It seems that it would act as a literal match character ":".  I'm unable to locate info that describes what special function the : has in a regular expression match pattern.

Comment: It's a [non capturing group](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `(?:a|b)` is the same as `(a|b)` except it doesn't create a backreference.